# Chrome Extension to C#?

Tags: javascript, c#, google-chrome

I got the following code which was written into a Chrome Extension (Javascript?)

```
;
(function() {
    function findCaptcha() {
        return document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha') || document.getElementById('g-recaptcha');
    }
    function completeCaptch(intervalID) {
        intervalID = setInterval(function() {
            if (findCaptcha() != null) {
                findCaptcha()
                    .remove();
                clearInterval(intervalID);
            }
        }, 200);
    }
    var loadedID = null;
    if (location.hash === '#checkout' || location.pathname === '/checkout') {
        completeCaptch(loadedID);
    }
    var stateID = null;
    window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        stateID = null;
        clearInterval(stateID);
        if (location.hash === '#checkout' || location.pathname === '/checkout') {
            completeCaptch(stateID);
        }
    }, false);
})();
```

Reading this code is simple enough, it calls the function completeCaptch with some sort of ID that is irrelevant and then calls the function findCaptch if it is present (return document.querySelector('.g-recaptcha') || document.getElementById('g-recaptcha');) and simply removes the document.ID by calling .remove();

This is code that bypasses reCAPTCHA in a demo and I was wondering if it is possible to convert this code (whatever it was written in) to C# if I were to use a .net WebBrowser.

Using a .net WebBrowser I would be able to getElementById but would I be able to call .remove() in C#?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checkout the [HtmlAgilityPack](http://www.nuget.org/packages/HtmlAgilityPack) library. It's a fantastic library for dealing with HTML DOMs, allowing you to do something like this:

```
doc.DocumentNode.SelectSingleNode("/xpath/to/node").Remove();
```